# Outlook Rules: Copy flagged item to sub-folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

A colleague had a rule in Outlook so that; when they flagged a message for follow-up it was copied to a sub-folder (called Follow-up) and when they removed the flag, the item was removed from the follow-up folder, but still available in the inbox (or whatever folder it was moved to).
This rule has disappeared in a move from Windows 7 to O365 (using desktop).
I am unable to replicate the rule.  Any ideas please?

Comment: Was it a Smart Folder that just showed all the items in the inbox which were flagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you mean followup search folder that is available in To-Do Bar:

[image]

Right? If so, take a look at the following Microsoft Support article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keep-upcoming-tasks-always-in-view-bcf25093-82f6-47f1-a7ec-cf9915186a99

Comment: Thanks Thims, I think it was quite simply that the Follow Up search folder needed dragging to Favourites, there wasn't any rule at all...